python and free variable name resolution
python 3.12 reference

4.2.6. Interaction with dynamic features
The eval() and exec() functions do not have access to the full
environment for resolving names. Names may be resolved in the local
and global namespaces of the caller. Free variables are not resolved
in the nearest enclosing namespace, but in the global namespace.

What does that mean? I can't really understand this. This code works as intended.
var = 'global'

def f0():
    var = 'local'
    def f1():
        print(var)
    return f1

def ftest(f):
    var = 'ftest'
    f()

ftest(f0())

#prints 'local' in python 3.10 interpreter (yeah, reference is from python 3.12)

But according to the reference it must print 'global', I guess???
Can someone explain this little paragraph? It seems like contradiction to me.

You quote a section on eval() and exec() but there's neither in your example code.

If f1() instead contained print(eval("var")), it would find "global" instead of "local" (since "local" is in an enclosing namespace, neither local nor global).

@Friedrich Well'p it was not 100% clear that it was only about eval() and exec()

As the comments point out, the section you quote is true only within eval and exec blocks. Consider this example code from the REPL:
>>> var = 'global'
>>> def f0():
...     var = 'function-local'
...     def f1():
...         print(eval('var'))
...     return f1
...
>>> def no_eval():
...     var = 'function-local'
...     def inner():
...         print(var)
...     return inner
...
>>> f0()()
global
>>> no_eval()()
function-local


thank you a lot! for me it was not clear that this referred just to the eval() and exec()
